# Disecting a group of words from an XML file and storing them in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, split

I have this XML file here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xml> 

<word> 
  <threeletter>RIP</threeletter>
  <threeletter>PIE</threeletter>  
  <fourletter>PIER</fourletter>
  <fourletter>RIPE</fourletter>
  <fiveletter>SPIRE</fiveletter> 
  <sixletter>SPIDER</sixletter> 
 </word>

 <word> 
  <threeletter>SUE</threeletter> 
  <threeletter>USE</threeletter> 
  <fourletter>EMUS</fourletter>
  <fourletter>MUSE</fourletter>
  <fiveletter>SERUM</fiveletter> 
  <sixletter>RESUME</sixletter> 
 </word>
</xml>
```

And then  I will load them and store these words in a array called word once the page is done loading

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax
    ({ 
        url: "dictionary.xml", 
        success: function( xml )
        { 
            $(xml).find("word").each(function()
            { 
            words.push($(this).text());
            }); 
        }       
    });
```

})

and then when I access each contents of `alert(word[0])` it shows me this result

```
RIP
PIE  
PIER
RIPE
SPIRE 
SPIDER
```

So I am assuming that word[0] is something like this, `word[0] = "RIP PIE PIER RIPE SPIRE SPIDER "`

but when I do this "

```
var x = word[0].split(" ");
                    alert(x[0]);
```

it is not giving me the word "RIP"
any idea why is this happening? I want to disect all of the words in `words[0]`(that came from an xml) and then split those words and store those words in an array but it seems to be not working any idea why?

Comment: you didn't ask, but.... the schema you've used in that XML file is sort of redundant and non-optimal.  Why would you use an element name to indicate the length of its value?  the length is easily calculable and could even be used in element selection should you need that (for example, "all 3 letter words under word[7]"). If you have control over the shape of the XML data, I'd suggest you convert all of those child elements to just text, and join them by spaces. (I assume no words have spaces in them).  `<root><word><children>rip ripe pier spire...</children></word>...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'dictionary.xml',
    async: false,
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("word").each(function(index) {
            words[index] = [];
            $(this).children().each(function() {
                words[index].push($(this).text());

            });
        });

    },
    dataType: 'XML'
});
console.log(words[0]);
console.log(words[1]);​
```

Comment: are you sure, because its perfectly working and this is how i see in my console, for words[0] and words[1]
["RIP", "PIE", "PIER", "RIPE", "SPIRE", "SPIDER"]
["SUE", "USE", "EMUS", "MUSE", "SERUM", "RESUME"]

Comment: do your console.log or alerts inside the success function

Comment: it is. I don't get it how it works, but index hasn't been declared but why sis it working?

Comment: oh that's no rocket science, ive edited my answer, please check

Comment: the ajax req is async by default, so the statements after it will be executed independent of the ajax completion. I made that async: false.
If you get your answer please consider marking it as answered.

Comment: can you explain this line please? words[index] = [];

Comment: you should really check this out first 
http://jqapi.com/#p=each

let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9815/discussion-between-userd-and-user962206)